# Can files in C:\WINDOWS\Temp be deleted and does Disk Cleanup do so?

Tags: windows, disk-space

It appears that files which currently aren't in use can be safely deleted from the C:\WINDOWS\Temp folder... Why doesn't [Disk Cleanup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_Cleanup) offer to do this automatically?

Comment: I think Disk Cleanup only clears tempfiles after a certain age... Have you tried CCleaner?

Answer (score 6):

I would use [CCleaner](http://www.ccleaner.com/) it's really awesome, after you have installed it just grab the executable and put on you USB key, and it's portable! (it doesn't need to be installed)

*CCleaner is a freeware system optimization, privacy and cleaning tool. It removes unused files from your system - allowing Windows to run faster and freeing up valuable hard disk space. It also cleans traces of your online activities such as your Internet history. Additionally it contains a fully featured registry cleaner. But the best part is that it's fast (normally taking less than a second to run) and contains NO Spyware or Adware! :)*

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in **most cases** you can delete the files not in use.

Sometimes (e.g. a installer runs in the background and unpacks itself before installing) it may be devastatingly bad idea.

So Disk Cleanup may be 'better safe then sorry'.

(But I thought it does this already, you learn something new everyday ...)

Answer (score 0):

I usually delete all files that have been created before the last reboot of the computer.
If it's too long, I keep files created the last 3 or 4 days and delete the others. If some are locked because they're in use, no problem as they won't be deleted.